# CSS Transform-origin on Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, transform

I am using several (about 50) Canvas elements to build an image that can be rotated 3D. The image is a label rotating around a bottle, so I need it to be in pieces. My code, currently works in all internet browsers, but I can't make it work in Android (have not tried iOS).

The first problem is the origin. Labels rotate, but the origin (z value) is not being set. I don't know if x and y work, but the Z value certainly does't. I used Google Chrome dev tools to set the browser to Android device (in my computer) and it works there. So, why not in my phone?

CSS (all elements are canvas):

```
.bottle_label_img
{
    position:           absolute;
    left:               142px;
    top:                220px;
    border:             none;
    height:             130px;
    width:              10px;
    /*transform-origin: 50% 50% 95px;*/
    transform-origin:   50% 50% 72px;
    transform-style:    preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 72px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

JavaScript to rotate (although this seems to work):

```
document.getElementById(Label_ids[i]).style.transform = 'rotateY(' + label_current_pos[i] + 'deg)';
$("#" + Label_ids[i]).css("-webkit-transform: ", "rotateY(" + label_current_pos[i] + 'deg)');
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Android version 4.4.4